# Very unusual rounding

Tags: java, math, rounding

Did you ever make a rounding like that:

- [0.95,1) rounds to 1
- [0.90,0.95) rounds to 0.95
- [0.85,0.90) rounds to 0.90
- [0.80,0.85) rounds to 0.85

I tried to do like this:

```
double rounded = Math.round(x * 20.0) / 20.0;
```

But it rounds a bit different, for example it rounds 0.91 to 0.90 and I rather need it to round 0.91 to 0.95

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number you're looking for can be found by

1. Multiplying your number by 20.
2. Computing the floor of your number.
3. Dividing your number by 20.
4. Adding 0.05

For example, ⌊ 0.95 * 20 ⌋ / 20 + 0.05 = ⌊ 19 ⌋ / 20 + 0.05 = 0.95 + 0.05 = 1.00.

In Java:

```
double result = Math.floor(x * 20.0) / 20.0 + 0.05;
```

Hope this helps!